# IOS 14 request limited photo access

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin

I'm trying to use PHPickerController and access PHAsset to get file name and file size but the PHAsset are null

```cs
var config = new PHPickerConfiguration(PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary) {
    Filter = PHPickerFilter.ImagesFilter,
    SelectionLimit = 1
};
var picker= new PHPickerViewController(config) {
    ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover,
    Delegate = new ImagePickerDelegate((fileSize, fileName, url) => {

    })
};

ViewController.PresentViewController(picker, true, null);
```

```cs
public class ImagePickerDelegate : PHPickerViewControllerDelegate
{
    public ImagePickerDelegate(Action<int, string, string> action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }

    public Action<int, string, string> Action { get; }

    public override void DidFinishPicking(PHPickerViewController picker, PHPickerResult[] results)
    {
        picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var asset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(result.AssetIdentifier, null)?.firstObject as PHAsset;
            // The asset are null
            var fileSize = asset.ValueForKey((NSString)"fileSize");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the image the request dialog show and code are not pause on following line

> var asset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(result.AssetIdentifier, null)?.firstObject as PHAsset;

and return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [FetchAssetsUsingLocalIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624732-fetchassetswithlocalidentifiers?language=objc) method to get **PHAsset** object, then it will return value.

Sample code as follows:

```
public override void DidFinishPicking(PHPickerViewController picker, PHPickerResult[] results)
{
    picker.DismissViewController(true, null);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
       var refID = result.AssetIdentifier;
       string[] refIDs = new string[] { refID };
       var asset = PHAsset.FetchAssetsUsingLocalIdentifiers(refIDs, null)?.firstObject as PHAsset;
       
       // var fileSize = asset.ValueForKey((NSString)"fileSize");
    }
}
```

Also could have a look at this [native code link](https://github.com/Jan-E/ikyle.me-code-examples/blob/master/Photo%20Picker%20ObjC/Photo%20Picker%20ObjC/PHPickerController.m#L223).